# How to add data to table that is existing

Tags: php, mysql, sql, where-clause

```
if (file_exists(TEMP.'/'."$check_dir".'/'."$endofname$test".'.jpeg')) 
        {
                echo "File : $endofname$test was made <br />";
                move($new_file_destination);

                $img_name = 'http:localhost/single4thenight/media/com_jomclassifieds/items/backpage/'."$check_dir".'/'."$endofname$test".'_1.jpeg, ';
                $img_title = "UPDATE iutca_jomcl_adverts SET images='$img_name' WHERE title='$title'";
                if ($conn->query($img_title) === TRUE) 
                    {
                        echo "Record updated successfully";
                    } else {
                            echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($conn);
                                }       
        }
```

I need to add data to a table that is existing but I want to add data to the table not erase it with the updating data

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. Are you saying you want to add a row to the table? Or are you saying you want to update an existing row in a table?

Comment: update the exiting row I need to add data to the data that is already in the table

Comment: The set name I need that not to erase the data that's already in that row image

Comment: So you want to append data to the existing value of a record's images column? If it was "image1.jpg" before, you want it to be "image1.jpg,image2.jpg" where title="$title"?

Comment: what I'm thinking is that you want to use the `CONCAT()` function or `CONCAT_WS()` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html - Those will add to an existing record if that is what the question is about. I too am having difficulty understanding the *ultimate goal*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to append (concatenate) a new value to the end of an existing row's value you will still need to use UPDATE.

It would look something like this:

`UPDATE iutca_jomcl_adverts SET images = CONCAT_WS('|', images, '$img_name') WHERE title='$title'`

([CONCAT_WS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) is "concatenate with separator")

However, that won't handle the case where the row doesn't already exist. In that case, you would need to do an `INSERT` and use MySQL's `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE images = CONCAT(images,'|$img_name')` (if `title` is a unique key).

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH BEEN WOKING ON THIS CODE ALL DAY STUMPED ME FOR ABOUT 8HRS

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the INSERT INTO SQL if you want to add a new row.

```
INSERT INTO table (column1, column2, ..., columnN) VALUES ('value_column1',...,'value_columnN')
```

If you want to add data to an existing row (not table), you should use UPDATE SQL setting only field you want to edit/add.

Comment: $img_title = "UPDATE iutca_jomcl_adverts SET images='$img_name' WHERE title='$title'";

Comment: I need it to go where title is not just anywhere

Answer (score 0):

You are updating rows using the UPDATE syntax. That only tells MySQL that you want to update data in that database NOT create a new row.

You will have to use the INSERT INTO syntax outlined in the MySQL documentation.

Comment: i cant just append to that row that is already there